# How to delete lines whose first field contains special characters only?

Tags: text-processing

How to delete lines which contains a `/` or `'` or `-` or `.` only in their first `|`-separated field?

- code tried:

  ```
  sed 's/^\.\d; /^\-/d; /^\//d' file > file_out
  ```
- example input :

  ```
  /|98374|
  /trust|q83129|
  //|392720|
  //cust|23892|
  .|9374|
  .abcd|28374|
  '|238674|
  'hcsu|3810|
  -|327492|
  -abcde|9837|
  ```
- expected output:

  ```
  .abcd|28374|
  /trust|q83129|
  //cust|23892|
  'hcsu|3810|
  -abcde|9837|
  ```

Comment: How do you expect the output to be sorted? Why is `.abcd|28374|` first in output, while it is not in input?

Comment: If one of the solutions worked for you, please consider [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.

Answer (score 6):

"Mandatory" `awk`-based solution :)

```
awk -F'|' '$1 !~ /^[\/'\''.-]+$/' input.txt
```

This will set the field separator to `|` and only print if the condition *"the first field ( `$1`) does not match the RegEx (`!~`) 'consists only of `/`,`'`,`.` or `-`' (`^[/'.-]+$`, with proper escaping)"* is fulfilled.

Notice that the syntax to express this is a little involved, because the `awk` program needs to be enclosed in single-quotes (`' ... '`), otherwise the shell would interpret statements like `$1` before they reach `awk`. Therefore, the character list contains an "interruption" to the single-quoting (the first `'`), then an escaped literal single-quote (`\'`), and then a continuation of the single-quoted `awk` program.

Alternatively, and maybe a little easier to read, write the `awk` program as concatenation of a `'...'`-quoted string, a `"..."`-quoted string and another `'...'`-quoted string:

```
awk -F'|' '$1 !~ /^'"[\/'.-]"'+$/' input.txt
```

Comment: Wouldn't `awk "!/^[/'.-]+[|]/" input.txt` be easier ?

Comment: @QuartzCristal Yes and no. On the algorithmic side yes - it is a shorter notation to restrict the search to the first pipe-separated field (but is assumes there is one, and if more field-based filtering is desired later, the explicit specification may also be more beneficial). On the syntax side no - the shell would mis-interpret the `!` as a meta-character (in particular, a history reference) when the program is put in double-quotes, so the reason for the involved "interrupted single-quoted program" notation is not resolved.

Comment: The History Expansion issue is not a limitation in any sense. To avoid it: What about `awk \!"/^[/'.-]+[|]/" input.txt` then ?

Comment: Note that `awk` is not *Mandatory* in any case. Both `sed` and `grep` (at least) could use similar regexes.

Comment: @QuartzCristal The "Mandatory" was meant tongue-in-cheek. On the other hand, it is a [mandatory tool for POSIX installations](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html), so the term is not too misleading either.

Comment: Tonge-in-cheek ... Cheers ! :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you mean delete lines whose first `|`-delimited field is entirely made of characters from the `.-/'` set only, then:

```
grep -vxE "[./'-]+(\|.*)?"
```

(removes (with `-v`) line entirely (`-x`) made of a sequence of 1 or more (`+`) characters in the `./'-` set, followed by an optional (`?`) `|` followed by any number (`*`) of characters (`.`)).

Or

```
grep -vE "^[./'-]+(\||\$)"
```

(removes lines starting (`^`) with a sequence of 1 or more (`+`) characters in the `./'-` set followed by either (`|`) `|` or the end of the line (`$` escaped as it's still special to the shell inside double quotes, though generally  not  when followed by a `)`)).

Replace `+` with `*` if you also want to remove lines whose first field is empty. Or use:

```
grep "^[^|]*[^|./'-]"
```

To search for lines that contain at least one character other (`^`) than `./'-` before the first `|`.

More generally, note that `sed /regexp/d` can be written `grep -v regexp` (and `sed '/re1/d; /re2/d'` -> `grep -v -e re1 -e re2`). `grep` besides being smaller and generally faster than `sed` also has the advantage of supported extended regexps portably, while not all `sed` implementations support `-E` yet. There are also more `grep` implementations that support `-P` for `perl` regexps than `sed` implementations that do.

Comment: In order to a *in their first | separated field* to exist, there must be a `|`, it could not be optional.

Comment: What is wrong with `grep -vE "^[./'-]+[|]" file` ?

Comment: @QuartzCristal, this accounts for potential lines with only one field, in which case there would be no `|`. Same as with `awk -F'|'`-based approaches

Comment: Repeating (without limit) the characters `|./'-` means accepting a `-----` first field, which is not what I understand from *a / or ' or - or . only`. It seems to me that it should be **only** one character.

Comment: @QuartzCristal, not sure what you mean not what you're referring to. Question says *How to delete lines whose first field contains special characters only?*.

Comment: @QuartzCristal and the OP's example explicitly deletes a line that contains two consecutive `//`, so it is not about first fields that consist of only one character.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect `s/^\.\d` to do? You open a `s`ubstitute command but you only close it accidently by some other slashes later on. You probably mean `/^\./d` to delete lines that that with a dot, but this will also delete the `.abcd` line.

But what you actually seem to want is to delete lines that don't have other characters than `./'-` before the `|`. So put this into your regular expression:

```
sed "/^[./'-]*|/d" < file > file_out
```

This will not reorder the printed lines (like in your desired output), but you didn't specify how to reorder it.

And your example doesn't show what to do with an empty first field. If this should be printed, use

```
sed "/^[./'-]\{1,\}|/d" < file > file_out
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring a (not specified) reorder of the output we can say.

A *contains a / or ' or - or . only* could be written as:

```
[/'.-]
```

In regex parlance: one character, either `/` or `'` or `.` or `-`. The `-` has been moved to the end so it doesn't mean a `range` to the regex engine.

It doesn't matter where it is used, in `sed` or `awk` or `grep`.

Then, that regex needs quoting to pass the shell, as it contains a `'`, it should be easier to quote with `"`. Then we add that the next character needs to be a `|` and we get a close approximation:

```
$ grep "^[/'.-][|]" file   # or awk "/^[/'.-][|]/" file   or   sed "/^[/'.-][|]/"\!d file
/|98374|
.|9374|
'|238674|
-|327492|
```

That doesn't select the `//|392720|` line as the `/` is actually repeated. If you need repeated characters then you need this regex (in BRE parlance):

```
^[/'.-]\{1,\}[|]        # or [/'.-]+[|] in ERE language.
```

Or, if only the `\` needs to be repeated:

```
"^[/'.-][/]\{0,1\}[|]"     # or ^[/'.-][/]?[|] in ERE
```

Having clarified the regex (and the shell quoting) needed, we can use either of:

```
grep -v   "^[/'.-][/]\{0,1\}[|]"   file
sed      "/^[/'.-][/]\{0,1\}[|]/d" file
awk    "! /^[/'.-][/]{0,1}[|]/"    file   # Using an space to prevent
                                          # History expansion of `!`.
awk    \!"/^[/'.-][/]{0,1}[|]/"    file   # Using a `\` to prevent
                                          # History expansion of `!`.
```

Or some Perl, Python program that could use the same regex.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
awk -F '|' "\$1 ~ /[^-./']|^$/" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.put if .grep( none /^ <[ \c[SOLIDUS] \c[APOSTROPHE] \c[HYPHEN-MINUS] \c[FULL STOP] ]>+ <?before "|"> /);'  file
```

Here's an answer that spells out the Unicode names of the characters to be excluded: you `grep` for `none` of the regex matches to be found (none-junction). In Raku a bespoke character class is created with `<[`…`]>`, and the zero-width positive lookahead detecting the `|` pipe separator is written `<?before "|">`. Note how precisely you can name characters, e.g. `\c[HYPHEN-MINUS]` and/or `\c[HYPHEN]` and/or `\c[MINUS]` , etc.

Sample Input:

```
/|98374|
/trust|q83129|
//|392720|
//cust|23892|
.|9374|
.abcd|28374|
'|238674|
'hcsu|3810|
-|327492|
-abcde|9837|
```

Sample Output:

```
/trust|q83129|
//cust|23892|
.abcd|28374|
'hcsu|3810|
-abcde|9837|
```

To retain blank lines where non-matching lines once existed, remove the `if` conditional:

```
~$ raku -ne '.grep( none /^ <[ \c[SOLIDUS] \c[APOSTROPHE] \c[HYPHEN-MINUS] \c[FULL STOP] ]>+ <?before "|"> /).put;' file

/trust|q83129|

//cust|23892|

.abcd|28374|

'hcsu|3810|

-abcde|9837|
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/grep
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement requirement "which contains a / or ' or - or . only in their first |-separated field" conflicts with the absence of  `//|392720|` in the example output.  I will assume the goal is to not print lines whose first field is composed exclusively of one of more of the specified characters.

Here is a Perl solution:

```
 1  #!/usr/bin/env perl
 2  use strict;
 3  use warnings;
 4  while (<>) {
 5      my @F = split /\|/;
 6      print if $F[0] !~ /^[\/\'\-\.]+$/;
 7  }
```

Line 1 lets the shell know this is a Perl script [1].

Line 2 "The strict pragma disables certain Perl expressions that could behave unexpectedly or are difficult to debug, turning them into errors. " [2]

Line 3 "The warnings pragma gives control over which warnings are enabled in which parts of a Perl program." [3]

Lines 4-7 form a `while` compound statement [4].

Line 4 the `while` loop expression uses the null filehandle `<>` (diamond operator) [5], allowing the solution to be used as a Unix filter [6].  For each line of input, `while` will assign the current line of input to the default input general variable `$_` [7] and evaluate `BLOCK`.

Line 5 creates an array [8] local variable [9] with name `@F`.  The contents of `@F` are provided by calling the `split` builtin function [10, 11] in list context [12].  `split` examines the current line of input, looking for separators according to a regular expression [13] for the field delimiter `/\|/`.  `split` returns the fields as a list.

Line 6 forms an `if` compound statement [14] using statement modifier syntax [15].  The first field is checked against a regular expression `/^[\/\'\-\.]+$/` using the negated binding operator `!~` [16].  Input lines that do not match the regular expression are printed.

The solution produces output in the same order as the input:

```
$ perl solution.pl input.txt 
/trust|q83129|
//cust|23892|
.abcd|28374|
'hcsu|3810|
-abcde|9837|
```

References:

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

[2] https://perldoc.perl.org/strict

[3] https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings

[4] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Compound-Statements

[5] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I%2FO-Operators

[6] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(software)#Unix

[7] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#General-Variables

[8] https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata

[9] https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my

[10] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc

[11] https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split

[12] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary#context

[13] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre

[14] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Compound-Statements

[15] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers

[16] https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Binding-Operators